# Call specific extbase action for plugin

Tags: php, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I am developing a TYPO3 Extbase-Extension, which fetches events from an XML-API.
The Extension consists of 1 controller and 2 actions.

So my `ext_localconf.php` looks somewhat like this:

```
Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::configurePlugin($_EXTKEY, 'pi1', array(
    'Api' => 'latest,full'
),
array(
    'Api' => 'latest,full'
));
```

The contents of the actions are almost the same, the `latest`-Action fetches only 3 events from the API, the `full`-Action fetches all events from the API. Also they do render the events a bit differently, meaning they use different templates.

Now in the TYPO3-Backend on `Page A`I'm adding a new content with type of `plugin`. I select my plugin save the content. In the frontend the results produced by the `latest`-Action of the plugin are output.

However on `Page B`, I also want to use the same plugin, but want to output the results of the `full`-Action.

I am kinda confused. How can I select the action in a dropdown in the backend or something?

Documentation on TYPO3 is really bad and lacks lots of information, so I am looking here for help.

All examples that I found only deal with one action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a flexform for the plugin , or if your plugin has a flexform now just add the following.

To be able for choosing the actions and controller within a plugin you need to use `switchableControllerActions` in flexform.

```
<switchableControllerActions>
    <TCEforms>
         <label>View</label>
         <onChange>reload</onChange>
         <config>
           <type>select</type>
           <items type="array">
               <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                 <numIndex index="0">Latest events</numIndex>
                 <numIndex index="1">Api->latest;</numIndex>
               </numIndex> 
               <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                 <numIndex index="0">All events</numIndex>
                 <numIndex index="1">Api->full;</numIndex>
               </numIndex>               
            </items>
         </config>
     </TCEforms>
</switchableControllerActions>
```

If you don't have a flexform for extension create one in Configuration/Flexform folder. Check this link. https://wiki.typo3.org/Extension_Development,_using_Flexforms

Comment: Thank you. I don't have flexform yet. I will check out your link and come back to give some feedback.

Comment: Its simple, just follow the link i added in the post.. Ask me if you have questions :)

Comment: Add first I didn't really read your code example. Just the term "flexform" popped up and I started researching. I built a select field and then didn't manage it to call the selected value as an action. Then I revisited this page and saw, that you use a `swticthableControllerActions`-element. That did the trick :)